# Importar Excel con información adicional Excel Maatwebsite LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, maatwebsite

me disculpo por no dejar código, y es que no se por donde empezar.
Tengo un formulario en el cual debería subir un documento CSV junto a un campo adicional de texto, todo esto debería guardarse en una sola tabla de mi DB, es decir que cada registro que se forme en la tabla debería tener un campo adicional que tendría que tener la misma información del campo de texto en el formulario , utilizo Excel maatwebsite para subir el CSV, pero por mas que leo la documentación no encuentro una forma de ayudarme con mi problema.

Comment: Jamas lo hice en con archivos .csv, te serviría con archivos excel?

Comment: si no hay problema, el detalle se encuentra en agregar información adicional

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo una archivo excel con los titulos : `{nombre,carnet_identidad,edad,adicional}` en la primera fila.

Y teniendo una tabla **ejemplo** en la base de datos con `{nombre,ci,edad}` podemos realizar un formulario para subir la informacion de dicho archivo excel:

```
{!!Form::open(['route'=>'ballot.import', 'id'=>'cargar_exceldatos','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true, 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'class'=>'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form'])!!}
        @component('component::errors')@endcomponent
        <div class="col col-md-12 text-center">
            <div id="notificacion_resul_fcdu"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="token" />
            <div class="form-group has-success">
                {!!Form::file('doc_excel',['id'=>'doc_excel','class'=>'filestyle form-control', 'data-buttonText' => '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Excel','data-buttonName'=>'btn-success', 'required' => 'required'])!!}
            </div>
            {{ btn_save() }}
            <a href="{{ URL::previous() }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-md"><i class="fa fa-history"></i> Volver Atras </a>
        </div>
    {!!Form::close()!!}
```

Y una ruta definida:

```
Route::post('ballot/import', 'Liquidation\PlanillaController@postGuardarExcel')->name('ballot.import');
```

Entonces se puede crear una funcion de la siguiente manera:

```
public function postGuardarExcel(Request $request) {
    //iniciamos guardando el archivo en alguna direccion de tu proyecto
    $archivo = $request->file('doc_excel');
    $timestamp = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
    $nombre_original = $timestamp. '-' .$archivo->getClientOriginalName();
    $r1 = Storage::disk('archivos')->put($nombre_original,  \File::get($archivo) );
    //hasta aqui el guardado

    //ahora lo recuperamos para poder trabajar en el
    $ruta = storage_path('archivos') ."/". $nombre_original;
    if($r1) {
        Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($ruta, function($hoja){
            foreach($hoja->get() as $index => $fila){
                    DB::table('planillas')->insert([
                        'nombre'=>$fila->nombre,
                        'ci'=>$fila->carnet_identidad,
                        'edad'=> $fila->edad,
                    ]);
                   $dato_adicional=$fila->adicional
                  //y apartir de aqui puedes hacer lo que desees con el dato adicional.
                }         
            }
        });

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true
    ]);
}
```

Espero que este pequeño ejemplo te sirva de algo.